# Play framework - testing POST controller method

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework-2.1

I wanted to test one of my POST methods in my controller, so I written something like this:

```
@Test
    public void shouldSaveNewCollectionToDatabase(){
        String body = "{\"name\":\"collectionName\", \"owner\": {}}";
        JsonNode json = Json.parse(body);
        FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest(POST, "/rest/collections/add").withJsonBody(json);

        Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.SetsAndCollections.postCollection(), request);
        verify(questionSetCollectionDAO).save(any(QuestionSetCollection.class));
    }
```

the thing is, this test fails because controller method is not invoked at all so my `questionSetCollectionDAO` methods are not invoked.

I event put some printing at the top of the method:

```
@BodyParser.Of(Json.class)
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result postCollection(){
    System.out.println("I am here");
...
```

and I don't see any output on console.

If that is not the way I could invoke controller methods with fake requests, how can I do that?

I read about `fakeApplication` but I is there any other way to do some simple testing of `POST` controller methods?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or find anything else?

Answer (score 2):

For testing your rest services, first of all you should start a fake application.

```
FakeApplication fakeApplication=fakeApplication();
start(fakeApplication);
```

And at end pf your Test it is recommanded to stop it

```
    stop(fakeApplication);
```

If you have many test methods you can add these methods in your Test Class to facilitate test process.

```
FakeApplication fakeApplication = fakeApplication();

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    start(fakeApplication);
}

@After
public void afterTest() {
    stop(fakeApplication);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print out the http status code of your results? If it is a 303 redirect - which it sounds like it is (since the controller is not getting called), it is most likely that you need to provide a login play-session cookie to execute the POST method.

See this answer on how to get an auth cookie in Play 2:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953375/286550