# Play! framework FunctionalTest ignores the login operation in a secured application

Tags: playframework

I'm using **Play! v1.2.6**, and the secure module.

I want to test some of my controllers, so I wrote a `FunctionalTest`. My concern is that any page in my application is secured, so the user (or the test class) has to log-in first. I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762246/playframework-secure-module-how-do-you-log-in-to-test-a-secured-controller-in) on SO, so I wrote the following code:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {

    // Simulate a login and create a new request...
    public Request createAuthenticatedRequest(String url) {
        Map<String, String> loginInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        loginInfo.put("username", "test-user");
        loginInfo.put("password", "test-password");
        Response loginResponse = POST("/login", loginInfo);

        Request request = newRequest();
        request.cookies = loginResponse.cookies;
        request.url = url;
        return request;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_summary_page() {
        Request request = createAuthenticatedRequest("/summary");
        Response response = makeRequest(request);

        System.out.println("==================");
        System.out.println("Content: '" + getContent(response) + "'");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println(" > " + response.headers.get("Location") + " ; " + response.status);
        System.out.println("==================");

        assertIsOk(response);
        assertContentMatch("Summary page", response);
        assertContentType("text/html", response);
        assertCharset(play.Play.defaultWebEncoding, response);
    }
```

However, this is not working. The output of the test method is the following:

```
==================
Content: ''
------------------
 > [/login] ; 302
==================
```

which means that the request was redirected (HTTP code `302`) to the login page, like if the user was not logged.

Also, in my Secure class, I added a log message in the method `boolean authenticate(String username, String password)` to see if there is indeed an authentication attempt, but the log is **not** displayed when running the `FunctionalTest`.

What I am doing wrong? How can I fix my issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, and of course, it was a stupid error in my code.
Indeed, I post the request to the URL `/login`, instead of posting it to `/secure/authenticate`.

The correct code is thus:

```
public Request createAuthenticatedRequest(String url) {
    Map<String, String> loginInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    loginInfo.put("username", "test-user");
    loginInfo.put("password", "test-password");
    Response loginResponse = POST("/secure/authenticate", loginInfo);
    Request request = newRequest();
    request.cookies = loginResponse.cookies;
    request.url = url;
    return request;
}
```